# WordPress - newbie confusion alert

Tags: wordpress

I've not really used WP before but now I have to learn it and quickly too :( I have been coding with PHP and building my own CMSs - but I find WP a bit/very confusing. ( Partly the terminology 'Blog' 'Post' etc - I don't want to blog.. just build a website! )

Short story: my client has had a home page and content page designed and wants it produced in WP. I told her that the design wouldn't be exactly as she has designed it as it will need to fit into a WP template. ( I found one that's not a zillion miles off ) . But - I'm starting to wonder if I've given her bad info - that you can in fact build any page and have it as part of a WP theme/install / whatever? Is that the case? If so how do you edit the page through the CMS?

Thanks

Comment: Have a look at the [Wordpress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/) and read a bit about the capabilities of Wordpress, its Themes and Plugins. Wordpress is quite a powerful CMS, for blogs as well as for static pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll try to get you started. You can make a WordPress site look like anything you want. Yes, you have to start from some kind of theme. This can be an existing finished theme, a blank starter theme, or you can create the theme files yourself and start from scratch. First thing for you to do is familiarize yourself with the theme file structure and each file's purpose. This will get you a LONG way.

Once you've chosen a theme to start from, and coded the general look and structure of the site, you can start to theme individual pages that may look somewhat different from the general structure. The way to do this is to create a file (I usually duplicate and rename the page.php file) and rename it to page-templatename.php - 'templatename' being replaced by whatever you want to call the page. Then in the page you add a php comment at the top saying Template Name: You Template Name Here. From the WP backend page editor you can then select this template from the page template selection on the right.

Take the time to do the due diligence of learning the file structure, you will be well on your way with the other experience that you have. Lean on the wordpress codex: codex.wordpress.org

Comment: Thanks everyone - I don't know why I'm finding this so difficult - stupidity comes to mind! I will give it a go..

Jim

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a template with `index.php` and `CSS` (style.css) located in under wp-content/theme and activate it from back-end. If you dont want to have any wordpress functionality and have a basic layout you can create even though.

For Example -

Under `\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\yourthemename` create index.php and post code like --

```
<?php
/**
 * The main template file.
 *
 * This is the most generic template file in a WordPress theme
 * and one of the two required files for a theme (the other being style.css).
 * It is used to display a page when nothing more specific matches a query.
 * E.g., it puts together the home page when no home.php file exists.
 * Learn more: http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage yourthemename
 */
```

and in style.css use this **CSS**

```
/*
Theme Name: yourthemename
Theme URI: http://wordpress.org/extend/themes/troop
Author: Swapnesh Sinha
Author URI: http://swapneshsinha.wordpress.com/
Description: nice theme from wordpress labs.
Version: 1.0
License: GNU General Public License v2 or later
License URI: http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

See part 2 of this: [WP Theme Guide](http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/complete-wordpress-theme-guide)

Answer (score 0):

You can make WordPress do and look pretty much how you like.

Start out by reading the Codex on [Theme Development](http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development). I also find the [template hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy) a useful resource.

If the site is simple, you won't need much more than a style sheet and index.php file in your theme.